# Is it OK to use 'window' as an event bus in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I've been playing around with jQuery's Events methods and I built a simple event bus with the following code:

```
$(window).on('test:event', function (event, data) {
    console.log('Saw a test event: event=%o, data=%o', event, data);
});

$(window).trigger('test:event', {test_data: 'foo'});
```

My question is, are there any problems with using 'window' to manage the events?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is a great way of using the power of custom jQuery events outside of the context of DOM bubbling. But it can also be done more efficiently (without querying the DOM, since that's performance-expensive and unrelated to the requirements *I assume*), by using an empty object `{}` instead of the window.

[Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/) wrote a great [jQuery plugin](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/661855) for managing events in this way that eschews some of the irrelevant jQuery events elements while using the same principle to achieve a lightweight [Publish / Subscribe pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) (listen for and trigger events defined by strings, with optional extra arbitrary data passed between).

Comment: Having the expense of querying the DOM was exactly what I was worried about.  I hadn't considered using an empty object.  I'll definitely check out that plugin.

Comment: Would using an empty object maintain a single place for tracking the events?  My expectation is it would create a new object every time so the .on() would be listening on one empty object but the .trigger() would be attached to a different empty object.

Comment: Not if you continuously refer to the same jQuery selection of the same empty object. This is why the example uses a closure to keep the reference of `o` pointing to `$({})`, on which all events are triggered, listened for, and unbound. The closure wouldn't necessarily be necessary for your example — you'd just need to keep the same reference rather than creating a new jQuery selection each time: `var eventBus = $({}); eventBus.on('some:thing', function(){…}); eventBus.trigger('some:thing', {foo:bar})`, etc…

Comment: Right.  I noticed that in the jquery-tiny-pubsub plugin about 30 seconds after I asked. :)  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! Figuring out advanced event patterns outside of DOM relations really changed the way I looked at JS programming — and got me into the whole code design patterns thang.