# VueJs 2.0 emit event from grand child to his grand parent component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

It seems that Vue.js 2.0 doesn't emit events from a grand child to his grand parent component.

```
Vue.component('parent', {
  template: '<div>I am the parent - {{ action }} <child @eventtriggered="performAction"></child></div>',
  data(){
    return {
      action: 'No action'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    performAction() { this.action = 'actionDone' }
  }
})

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div>I am the child <grand-child></grand-child></div>'
})

Vue.component('grand-child', {
  template: '<div>I am the grand-child <button @click="doEvent">Do Event</button></div>',
  methods: {
    doEvent() { this.$emit('eventtriggered') }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

This JsFiddle solves the issue https://jsfiddle.net/y5dvkqbd/4/ , but by emtting two events:

- One from grand child to middle component
- Then emitting again from middle component to grand parent

Adding this middle event seems repetitive and unneccessary. Is there a way to emit directly to grand parent that I am not aware of?

Comment: have a look at `provide/inject`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER (Nov-2018 update)**

I discovered that we could actually do this by leveraging the `$parent` property in the grand child component:

```
this.$parent.$emit("submit", {somekey: somevalue})
```

Much cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Note that this only works if the relationship is child -> grandparent. This does *not* work if the child can be nested arbitrary levels deep.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55650245/841591 in response to the comment from @Qtax

Comment: You don't want that kind of things happening in your big project. You put the 'child' in a `transition` or whatever other wrapper component and it will break, leaving you with a big question mark in your head.

Comment: @AdamOrlov I agree, this is bad practice. Please handle events like this using a Vuex store.

Comment: You beautiful beautiful person.

Answer (score 156):

Vue 2.4 introduced a way to easily pass events up the hierarchy using `vm.$listeners`

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners :

> Contains parent-scope `v-on` event listeners (without `.native` modifiers). This can be passed down to an inner component via `v-on="$listeners"` - useful when creating transparent wrapper components.

See the snippet below using `v-on="$listeners"` in the `grand-child` component in the `child` template:

```js
Vue.component('parent', {
  template:
    '<div>' +
      '<p>I am the parent. The value is {{displayValue}}.</p>' +
      '<child @toggle-value="toggleValue"></child>' +
    '</div>',
  data() {
    return {
      value: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleValue() { this.value = !this.value }
  },
  computed: {
    displayValue() {
      return (this.value ? "ON" : "OFF")
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('child', {
  template:
    '<div class="child">' +
      '<p>I am the child. I\'m just a wrapper providing some UI.</p>' +
      '<grand-child v-on="$listeners"></grand-child>' +
    '</div>'
})

Vue.component('grand-child', {
  template:
    '<div class="child">' +
      '<p>I am the grand-child: ' +
        '<button @click="emitToggleEvent">Toggle the value</button>' +
      '</p>' +
    '</div>',
  methods: {
    emitToggleEvent() { this.$emit('toggle-value') }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.child {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #f0f0f0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <parent></parent>
</div>
```

Answer (score 50):

The Vue community generally favors using Vuex to solve this kind of issue. Changes are made to Vuex state and the DOM representation just flows from that, eliminating the need for events in many cases.

Barring that, re-emitting would probably be the next best choice, and *lastly* you might choose to use an event bus as detailed in the other highly voted answer to this question.

The answer below is my original answer to this question and is not an approach I would take now, having more experience with Vue.

---

This is a case where I might disagree with Vue's design choice and resort to DOM.

In `grand-child`,

```
methods: {
    doEvent() { 
        try {
            this.$el.dispatchEvent(new Event("eventtriggered"));
        } catch (e) {
            // handle IE not supporting Event constructor
            var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
            evt.initEvent("eventtriggered", true, false);
            this.$el.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

and in `parent`,

```
mounted(){
    this.$el.addEventListener("eventtriggered", () => this.performAction())
}
```

Otherwise, yes, you have to re-emit, or use a bus.

Note: I added code in the doEvent method to handle IE; that code could be extracted in a reusable way.

Comment: This behaves differently for IE? wasn't aware there were browser discrepancies with vue...

Comment: @BassemLhm Vue is fine with IE. The problem with IE is not Vue, it's this is a DOM solution and you cannot do new Event() in IE. You have to document.createEvent(). I can add the IE support if needed.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to install vuex just for one simple case.

Comment: @AdamOrlov I agree with you.

Comment: A simpler solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55650245/841591

Answer (score 30):

Yes, you're correct events only go from child to parent. They don't go further, e.g. from child to grandparent.

The Vue documentation (briefly) addresses this situation in the [Non Parent-Child Communication](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) section.

The general idea is that in the grandparent component you create an empty `Vue` component that is passed from grandparent down to the children and grandchildren via props. The grandparent then listens for events and grandchildren emit events on that "event bus".

Some applications use a global event bus instead of a per-component event bus. Using a global event bus means you will need to have unique event names or namespacing so events don't clash between different components.

Here is an example of [how to implement a simple global event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/).

Answer (score 26):

If you want to be flexible and simply broadcast an event to all parents and their parents recursively up to the root, you could do something like:

```
let vm = this.$parent

while(vm) {
    vm.$emit('submit')
    vm = vm.$parent
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Another solution will be on/emit at **root** node:

Uses `vm.$root.$emit` in **grand-child**, then uses `vm.$root.$on` at the ancestor (or anywhere you'd like).

**Updated**: sometimes you'd like to disable the listener at some specific situations, use [vm.$off](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-off) (for example:  `vm.$root.off('event-name')` inside lifecycle hook=**beforeDestroy**).

```js
Vue.component('parent', {
  template: '<div><button @click="toggleEventListener()">Listener is {{eventEnable ? "On" : "Off"}}</button>I am the parent - {{ action }} <child @eventtriggered="performAction"></child></div>',
  data(){
    return {
      action: 1,
      eventEnable: false
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.addEventListener()
  },
  beforeDestroy: function () {
    this.removeEventListener()
  },
  methods: {
    performAction() { this.action += 1 },
    toggleEventListener: function () {
      if (this.eventEnable) {
        this.removeEventListener()
      } else {
        this.addEventListener()
      }
    },
    addEventListener: function () {
      this.$root.$on('eventtriggered1', () => {
        this.performAction()
      })
      this.eventEnable = true
    },
    removeEventListener: function () {
      this.$root.$off('eventtriggered1')
      this.eventEnable = false
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div>I am the child <grand-child @eventtriggered="doEvent"></grand-child></div>',
  methods: {
    doEvent() { 
        //this.$emit('eventtriggered') 
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('grand-child', {
  template: '<div>I am the grand-child <button @click="doEvent">Emit Event</button></div>',
  methods: {
    doEvent() { this.$root.$emit('eventtriggered1') }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <parent></parent>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

VueJS 2 components have a `$parent` property that contains their parent component.

That parent component also includes its own `$parent` property.

Then, accessing the "grandparent" component it's a matter of accessing the "parent's parent" component:

```
this.$parent["$parent"].$emit("myevent", { data: 123 });
```

Anyway, this is kinda *tricky*, and I recommend using a global state manager like Vuex or similar tools, as other responders have said.

Comment: This is not so great for a component that can be a child or a grandchild.

Comment: As I said, this solution is a trick. I recommend using a global state manager like Vuex or similar tools, as other responders have said.

Comment: Michael Rush's answer seens more suitable for those cases. It avoids creating methods just for emitting back the same message up the ancestral chain.

Answer (score 5):

This is the only case when I use [event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)!! For passing data from deep nested child, to not directly parent, communication.

> **First**: Create a js file (I name it eventbus.js) with this content:

```
import Vue from 'vue'    
Vue.prototype.$event = new Vue()
```

> **Second**: In your child component emit an event:

```
this.$event.$emit('event_name', 'data to pass')
```

> **Third**: In the parent listen to that event:

```
this.$event.$on('event_name', (data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

**Note:** If you don't want that event anymore please unregister it:

```
this.$event.$off('event_name')
```

> **INFO: No need to read the below personal opinion**

I don't like to use vuex for grand-child to grand-parent communication (Or similar communication level).

> #### In vue.js for passing data from grand-parent to grand-child you can use [provide/inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject). But there is not something similar for the opposite thing. (grand-child to grand-parent) So I use event bus whenever I have to do that kind of communication.

Comment: Inject a function provided in grandparent to grandchild

Answer (score 5):

I've made a short mixin based on @digout answer. You want to put it, before your Vue instance initialization (new Vue...) to use it globally in project. You can use it similarly to normal event.

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    $propagatedEmit: function (event, payload) {
      let vm = this.$parent;
      while (vm) {
        vm.$emit(event, payload);
        vm = vm.$parent;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: this solution is what I used for my implementation but I added an additional parameter `targetRef` that stops the propagation on the component that you're targeting.

The `while` condition would then include `&& vm.$refs[targetRef]` - *you'd also need to include that `ref` attribute on the targeted component*

In my use case I didn't need to tunnel all the way to root, saving a few events from firing and maybe a couple of precious nanoseconds of time

Answer (score 5):

Riffing off @kubaklam and @digout's answers, this is what I use to avoid emitting on every parent component between the grand-child and the (possibly distant) grandparent:

```
{
  methods: {
    tunnelEmit (event, ...payload) {
      let vm = this
      while (vm && !vm.$listeners[event]) {
        vm = vm.$parent
      }
      if (!vm) return console.error(`no target listener for event "${event}"`)
      vm.$emit(event, ...payload)
    }
  }
}
```

When building out a component with distant grand children where you don't want many/any components to be tied to the store, yet want the root component to act as a store/source of truth, this works quite well. This is similar to the data down actions up philosophy of Ember. Downside is that if you want to listen for that event on every parent in between, then this won't work. But then you can use $propogateEmit as in above answer by @kubaklam.

Edit: initial vm should be set to the component, and not the component's parent. I.e. `let vm = this` and not `let vm = this.$parent`

Answer (score 1):

As of **Vue 3**, a number of fundamental changes have happened to root events:

The `$on`, `$off` and `$once` root methods no longer exist. There is to a certain extent something to replace this, since you can [listen to root events](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#root-component-events) by doing this:

```
createApp(App, {
  // Listen for the 'expand' event
  onExpand() {
    console.log('expand')
  }
})
```

Another solution are event buses, but the Vue.js documents take a dim view - they can cause maintenance headaches in the long run. You might get an ever spreading set of emits and event sinks, with no clear or central idea of how it is managed or what components could be affected elsewhere. Nonetheless, examples given by the docs of event buses are [mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt) and [tiny-emitter](https://github.com/scottcorgan/tiny-emitter).

However the docs make it clear that they recommend handling these sorts of situations in this order:

- **Props** A convenient solution for parent / child communications.
- **Provide/Inject** A simple way for ancestors to communicate with their descendants (although critically, not the other way around).
- **Vuex** A way of handling global state in a clear fashion. It's important to note that this is not solely for events, or communications - Vuex was built primarily to handle state.

Essentially the choice for the OP would come down to using an event bus, or Vuex. In order to centralise the event bus, you could place it inside Vuex, if state was also needed to be globally available. Otherwise using an event bus with strict centralised controls on it's behaviour and location might help.

Answer (score 1):

Riffing off @digout answer. I am thinking that if the purpose is to send data to a far-ancestor then we don't need $emit at all. I did this for my edge-case and it seems to work. Yes, it could be implemented via a mixin but it doesn't have to be.

```
/**
 * Send some content as a "message" to a named ancestor of the component calling this method.
 * This is an edge-case method where you need to send a message many levels above the calling component.
 * Your target component must have a receiveFromDescendant(content) method and it decides what
 * to do with the content it gets.
 * @param {string} name - the name of the Vue component eg name: 'myComponentName'
 * @param {object} content - the message content
 */
messageNamedAncestor: function (name, content) {
  let vm = this.$parent
  let found = false
  while (vm && !found) {
    if (vm.$vnode.tag.indexOf('-' + name) > -1) {
      if (vm.receiveFromDescendant) {
        found = true
        vm.receiveFromDescendant(content)
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Found the target component named ${name} but you dont have a receiveFromDescendant method there.`)
      }
    } else {
      vm = vm.$parent
    }
  }
}
```

Given an ancestor:

```
export default {
  name: 'myGreatAncestor',
  ...
  methods: {
     receiveFromDescendant (content) {
        console.log(content)
     }
   }
}
```

A great grand-child says

```
// Tell the ancestor component something important
this.messageNamedAncestor('myGreatAncestor', {
  importantInformation: 'Hello from your great descendant'
})
```

Comment: That’s a very neat way of solving this. And the event is not broadcasting everywhere. Instead of using the ancestor name, I would prefer to name my event, and any ancestor with a `messageNamedAncestor` method that returns `true` will end the research (`true` means it consumes the event/message).

Answer (score 0):

I really dig the way this is handled by creating a class that is bound to the window and simplifying the broadcast/listen setup to work wherever you are in the Vue app.

```
window.Event = new class {

    constructor() {
        this.vue = new Vue();
    }

    fire(event, data = null) {
        this.vue.$emit(event, data);
    }

    listen() {
        this.vue.$on(event, callback);  
    }

}
```

Now you can just fire / broadcast / whatever from anywhere by calling:

```
Event.fire('do-the-thing');
```

...and you can listen in a parent, grandparent, whatever you want by calling:

```
Event.listen('do-the-thing', () => {
    alert('Doing the thing!');
});
```

Comment: I would highly recommend *not* attaching random properties to the window object, since it's very easy to overwrite existing properties or conflict with existing 3rd party libraries.  Instead, anybody using Vue to solve this problem should instead use @roli roli's answer

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand or agree with this concern.  Binding to the prototype is a fine approach but binding to the window is just as, if not even more, common and probably a more standard way of handling this.  You name the property, so it's simple to avoid naming conflicts.

https://medium.com/@amitavroy7/vue-js-and-event-bus-approach-d46c50c56451
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008464/is-it-ok-to-use-window-as-an-event-bus-in-jquery

This is also the proposed solution Jeff Way uses on Laracasts.

https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/13