# Other than using an event bus, what's a good way to capture event emitted by a grandchild component in a grandparent component?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babeljs, vuejs2

Let's say I have 3 components in a parent-child relationship.

`Component1` is a parent of `Component2` and `Component2` is a parent of `Component3`.

`Component3` emits an `event1`. Typically, `event1` is handled in `Component2` but in my particular case, I want to handle it in `Component1`.

**Backstory**

The reason why I have set up my components this way, is because `Component2` is a generic component whose content is `Component3`. Tomorrow, I can create another `Component4` and pass it to `Component2` as a prop. Any event emitted from `Component4` or `Component3` needs to be accessed from an event handler in `Component1`'s template like

```
<template>
<component2 @event1="doSomething"></component2>
</template>
```

Comment: If you have a generic component that will be use by many components see mixin : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: Yes, but those examples are in regular JS format while mine is in `.vue`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615445/vuejs-2-0-emit-event-from-grand-child-to-his-grand-parent-component

Comment: You might consider passing your component into [slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Single-Slot) rather than as a prop.

Comment: You could try Centralized State Management using [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex)

Comment: @RoyJ, I tried using slots but I was only able to insert templates that way. I had generic and specific component methods as well, so slots weren't suitable.