# How to emit events in a functional Vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I wrote a [functional component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) that compiles form fields for certain conditions. The form fields are their own component. So I have three levels:

```
<FormComponent>          // handles input events
  <FunctionalComponent>  // selects form fields
    <FormFieldComponent> // emits input events
  </FunctionalComponent>
</FormComponent>
```

Functional components have no `this`, but get a context object as argument to the render function. What I could do is using `context.data.on[eventName](event)` or some similar construct. I also know that I could use an event bus or the dom elements directly, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615445/vuejs-2-0-emit-event-from-grand-child-to-his-grand-parent-component).

All this looks rather dirty to me.
Is there any `this.$emit` equivalent in functional components?

Comment: Are you saying you want your FunctionalComponent to bubble events from your FormFieldComponent to your FormComponent?

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3348

Comment: Yes, that is it! It took me a minute to wrap my head around it but that should solve my problem. Thanks a lot @RoyJ

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @RoyJ 's comment, I was able to solve my problem. Here for everyone who may face the same problem:

As described in a [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3348), the second argument for the render function has a data object that contains all the listeners and more. So the easiest way is to just directly give it to the child component:

```
render(h, context) {
  return h(FormFieldComponent, context.data, children)
}
```

In my specific case, I only take the listeners directly, because I manipulate large parts of the data object:

```
render(h, context) {
  const data = createDataObject()
  data.on = context.data.on

  return h(FormFieldComponent, data, children)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it looks a functional component emitting an event:

```
export default {
  functional: true,
  render(createElement, { listeners }) {
    return createElement(
      "button",
      {
        on: {
          click: event => {
            const emit_event = listeners.event_from_child; //> the name is: event_from_child
            emit_event("Hello World!Is this the message we excpected? :/");
          }
        }
      },
      "Pass event to parent"
    );
  }
};
```

And listening to the parent component:

```
<functional-component @event_from_child="event_from_child"></functional-component>
```

**See it in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2nm1zxv8o)**