# Vue: $emit to parents of parents

Tags: vuejs2

I have a child component that needs to say something to the parent of a parent (the grandparent?). Right now, this only works if the parent acts as a conduit:

from the child component, I call `this.$emit('hello', 'hi grandma!')`. Then the parent does the same from the `sayHello` method, and then the grandparent finally receives the data:

```
<grandparent>
  <parent @hello="sayHello">
    <child></child>
  </parent>
</grandparent>
```

is there a better way to communicate up the chain? It looks like the [docs recommend an event hub](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced); this strikes me as a more complicated solution?

Is there any reason I shouldn't use `this.$parent.$emit('hello', 'hi grandma!')`?

Comment: The docs *do* recommend a bus. Or you can use a state management solution. Or you can [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42615445/38065).

Comment: thanks. i just edited my question - can `this.$parent.$emit('hello', 'hi grandma!')` be a solution here, or is that bad practice?

Comment: That is a bad practice. Generally you don't want your components reaching out of themselves. Using $parent works if its a grandchild, but what if its a great grandchild?

Comment: thanks for the help here - and yes, this is definitely a dupe. my ultimate solution here was to chain together my `$emit`s in a way that envisions my components as mini api-like objects. although it feels a bit repetitive, i think it ultimately makes the components more flexible.  and i'm sure there is a good reason (performance?) for preventing endless emitting up the component tree.