# How can i listen for an event from a sub component in vue?

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js

I have 3 `components`

- `Stage`
- `StageComponent`
- `StageElementComponent`

the `Stage` contains the default data and the basic control of all 3 `components`.

the `StageComponent` i filter the `StageElementComponent` elements, and have some design, validations and user interactions in it.

the `StageElementComponent` display and element based on the user choise.

Things to take in account

I want to know if it is possible to `emit` an event from `StageElementComponent` and `listen` to it in the `Stage` component? like

```
<template>
    //StageElementComponent
    <div class="element d-flex flex-column justify-content-center"
        @dblclick="clear">
        <i class="material-icons" v-if="element" :class="[`bg-${element.type.color}`]">{{ element.type.icon }}</i>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props : {
            element : {
                type : Object,
                required : true
            }
        },
        methods : {
            clear : function($event) {
                this.$emit('clear', {
                    index : this.element.index
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss">
    .element {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

and in the `Stage` component listen to it like

```
<v-stage id="ticktr" class="section center" 
    :rows="height" 
    :columns="width" 
    :elements="elements"
    @clear="clearElement"></v-stage>
```

I do need these 3 components.

I don't want to listen and emit in the `StageComponent` as i would be repeating myself

I don't want to use `$root.$emit`.

It is possible to do this? how?

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615445/vuejs-2-0-emit-event-from-grand-child-to-his-grand-parent-component

Comment: Not possible under the constraints you list.

Comment: This looks like a job for Vuex. Then you can dispatch/commit  from any component and update the shared state.

Comment: You can pass a bus through StageComponent.