# How to pass params of a 'delegated' function to another function from child to parents?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, ecmascript-5, arrow-functions

I have a question. How can I call a (delegated) function and also add some parameters to it, is there a vay in javascript?

I have created a litle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/p7kL5mvw/

In the grandchild, I have a OnEdit function. It shall call its parents onEdit function, so the grandparent component receives a) the changed value and b) prop a and b from middle (TableView).

I look for something so I can say in this line:

`<click-to-edit v-model="todos[idx].text" :editable="true" :pOnEdit="onEdit"></click-to-edit>`

call onEdit function of my parent, pass the value which gave by my child and also add MY arguments, something like:

`:pOnEdit="onEdit(() => childArgument, todos[idx].a, todos[idx].b)`

Is it possible somehow, or how would you solve this problem? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJs 2.0 emit event from grand child to his grand parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615445/vuejs-2-0-emit-event-from-grand-child-to-his-grand-parent-component) .... the answers to this demonstrate *many* techniques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a solution. Since you can use javascript inside VueJS templates, it just works with:

`:pOnEdit="onEdit.bind(this, todos[idx].a, todos[idx].b)"`

Then the grandparent has arguments of grandchild and child. I hope it helps if someone has the same question :)

Comment: So now you'v changed what `this` means...before it was grandparent, now it's parent. Try to do something useful inside (not just logging) and you will see. Simply bad bad idea...

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean, sorry. I am not just logging them out, I actually use it like that and it works for me. 

In the mid-child, I pass ...arguments to the grandparent and grandparent receives all parameters I expected. I know I abused the context variable with 'this', but I actually don't need that context anyway, I just wanted to override the delegated function to apply additional arguments

Answer (score 1):

Just use [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Inside `click-to-edit` component

```html
<input @input="$emit('update', $event.target.value)" />
```

Parent:

```html
<click-to-edit v-model="todos[idx].text" :editable="true" @update="$emit('update', $event, todos[idx].a, todos[idx].b)"></click-to-edit>
```

Grand parent:

```html
<Parent @update="onUpdate" />
```

```js
methods: {
  onUpdate(childArgument, parentArgumentA, parentArgumentB) {
   // do whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this approach, this will for sure help many people. I actually have a similiar approach but I still am interested if there is a solution. I had similar cases before and I always had to look for another way, e.g. it might be possible that click-to-edit is a non-editable, imported library or whatever. 

I mean something like using apply/bind where you just append the function with its child function