# Use $emit without a click event

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue and there are some things I didn't understand yet.

[image]

In the first child there's a click event to $emit information to the next child. But in the other one, the second child, is there anyway to pass the information to the next child using $emit without a click  event or any other event (like scroll, hover etc)? I just want to pass it ahead. Can I use **mounted()**?

Comment: Related: [VueJs 2.0 emit event from grand child to his grand parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615445/vuejs-2-0-emit-event-from-grand-child-to-his-grand-parent-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! What you're looking for is [`$emit()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit), in combination with the [`v-on` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on), both of which it sounds like you're already using.

In the child component that you mention, the lowest one on the chain, you're already capturing a `click` event from some component, and then presumably using `$emit('my-event', [...some data...])` to emit a new event out from the child component itself.

All you need to do now is to add event listeners and handlers in the components up the chain, using Vue's [custom events mechanic](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html), so that they can receive and emit their own events, and the data can make it up to the parent. Custom events allow your components to emit and listen for events of any name, which may carry any data they'd like (this means they're not limited to being `click`/ `hover`/ `blur`/ etc.).

Here's the step-by-step of that approach:

(Structure: `Parent <--> Child #1 <--> Child #2 <--> Child #3`)

1. Child #3 captures a `click` event, and emits an event in its handler
2. Child #2 is listening for this event on #3, captures it, and `$emit`s its own event in its handler
3. Child #1 is listening for this event on #2, captures it, and emits own event in its handler
4. Parent captures event, and executes handler

---

In code, you'll have a listener and handler in each of your components, which can look something like this:
<sub>(I've used inline handlers here for brevity, but you can use defined methods as handlers too, just call `this.$emit(...)` from the method.)</sub>

*Child #3:*

```html
<component ... @click="$emit('my-event-a', $event)" />
```

*Child #2:*

```html
<ChildComponent3 ... @my-event-a="$emit('my-event-b', $event)" />
```

*Child #1:*

```html
<ChildComponent2 ... @my-event-b="$emit('my-event-c', $event)" />
```

*Parent:*

```html
<ChildComponent1 ... @my-event-c="myHandler" />
```

`$event` here is just [special Vue syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event) for referencing the event data in an inline handler, which in this case allows your new event to contain the same data.

The events in the various child components can be named whatever you'd like, just make sure that the respective listeners are listening for the correct event name (eg. `@event-x="..."` for `$emit('event-x')` and `@pizza-eaten="..."` for `$emit('pizza-eaten')`).

I also wanted to mention that passing the `event` object (or any data at all) with an emitted event is completely optional. To do so, just invoke `$emit` with the event name and no other arguments: `$emit('my-event')`. This is useful when you simply care *that* an event has occurred, and the handler requires no further info.

---

There are many ways to approach this problem, but this is the most straightforward to understand, and works great as long as you don't need tons of direct interaction between a component and its deeply nested children.

If you *do* find your component structure getting more complicated, then you may want to look into a fully realized [state management solution](https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-a-state-management-pattern), like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), which allows your components to interact with a state manager rather than having to deal with tons of events through a complicated component structure.