# Creating a styled component from another Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue 2 with Bootstrap application. I have many buttons that are similar to this:

```
<b-button variant="outline-secondary" title="..." v.b.tooltip.hover.bottom>
    <font-awesome-icon icon="..." />
</b-button>
```

The buttons differ in their titles and icons, but also in the event handlers used. In some places @click is used, in others @mouseenter, @mouseleave, and so on.

I want to wrap this into my own Vue component, so I can just specify a

```
<fancy-button title="..." icon="..." @eventA=... @eventB=... />
```

I want to do that without specifying all the event handlers on `fancy-button`, and without worrying about all the event modifiers. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615445/vuejs-2-0-emit-event-from-grand-child-to-his-grand-parent-component)

I just had to add `v-on="$listeners"` to `fancy-button`, and all events were passed to the parent without an issue.